# System repair or similar?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying so hard to use Ubuntu exclusively. 90% of the time it's fine, but there are so many issues out of the blue.

Rambox stopped working a while back. Nothing I do can get it working again.

The system locks up completely at least twice a week (when using Firefox) and I have to hard reboot. Tonight both Bluetooth mouse and keyboard failed to respond and only restoring a TimeShift snapshot resolved it.

Is there a system repair or something I can run? I'm assuming there are various corruptions causing these annoyances, but how can I diagnose them? I'm using 18.04, which I thought would be more stable to be honest.

Thanks

**Update #1**

$ sudo dmidecode -t 1,2

```
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: NOVATECH LTD
    Product Name: BB-47708B
    Version: 1.0
    Serial Number: 7347106-001
    UUID: 6DDE8894-8680-10B3-05B8-2E959170BBC1
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Family: To be filled by O.E.M.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Product Name: Z87-HD3
    Version: x.x
    Serial Number: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

**Update #2**

---

After trying to update AMD drivers I can only boot in recovery mode (and thus looks like no graphics drivers loaded at all:

@heynnema - output from commands:

```
:~$ dkms status
amdgpu, 19.20-812932: added
virtualbox, 5.2.34, 5.3.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.2.34, 5.3.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed

:~$ uname -r
5.3.0-40-generic
```

**Update #3**

Didn't restore TimeShift.

Ran `amdgpu-uninstall` which has fixed the problem, but guess I'm back with the old drivers.

```
$ dkms status
virtualbox, 5.2.34, 5.3.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.2.34, 5.3.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Update #4

Could the problem have been that I didn't run `apt update/upgrade` after installing the drivers ? (if they did actually install...)

Comment: Ubuntu is stable. These issues look like a hardware problem to me, or you did something wrong. There is no information to tell anything else.

Comment: I can suggest checking disks. Run `sudo touch /forcefsck` and reboot.

Comment: Advice: Pick ONE problem. Budget a few hours over the course of a week (or two) to learn the skills needed to diagnose and fix the problem. Use the Search box to see what others have asked about that problem. Keep notes of what you have learned about each problem. If you exhaust your calendar budget without solution, move that problem to the back of the queue and move on to the next problem. After a few iterations, un-solvable problems will suddenly seem much easier to diagnose and fix.

Comment: @user535733 Sensible comment. +1

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Also tell me the make/model of your computer, and the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Do you have a HDD or SSD?

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6 and that's part of my question. Where do I find the diagnostic information?

Comment: @Pilot6 roger@roger-BB-47708B:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        3.8G        7.9G        137M        3.8G         11G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
roger@roger-BB-47708B:~$

Comment: $ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
ls: cannot access '/home/roger/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory

Comment: $ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

Comment: @heynnema PC is a custom build. Intel® Core™ i7-4770K CPU @ 3.50GHz × 8 , AMD® Pitcairn. BIOS = 'F6'. I have one 120GB SSD (reformatted about 3 months ago) and a brand new 480GB SSH for my home folders. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit info like that into your question, not into the comments, please. Show me `sudo dmidecode -t 1,2`.

Comment: @heynnema Apologies. Post edited (not quite sure of the protocol on this forum!)

Comment: No worries. Once you paste text into your question, select the pasted text, then click the {} icon to make it human-readable. Look how nice it looks now. Anyway, please see my partial answer. Report back.

Comment: Regarding Rambox... do you have version 0.7.3? Snap version or .deb version?

Comment: @heynnema Yes Rambox is 0.7.3. I think it's snap. Installed via the Ubuntu software centre. TBH I'm not too bothered about it - but, for the sake of learning more Linux, I'd like to resolve it.

Comment: Do `snap list` and `snap remove` to get rid of the snap version, and try the .deb version at https://github.com/ramboxapp/community-edition/releases/download/0.7.3/Rambox-0.7.3-linux-amd64.deb

Answer (score 0):

**fsck**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

---

**Memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

---

**Rambox**

To try and cure the Rambox problem, uninstall the snap version, and install this .deb version [here](https://github.com/ramboxapp/community-edition/releases/download/0.7.3/Rambox-0.7.3-linux-amd64.deb).

---

**AMD**

You're behind with your AMD video driver for your [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn XT [Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition]. You have version 19.0.1, and the latest is 19.20, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-7000-series/amd-radeon-hd-7870-ghz-edition).

---

**BIOS**

**Note**: Perform a backup before updating the BIOS

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your hardware.

You have BIOS version F6. Version F8 can be downloaded from https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/GA-Z87-HD3-rev-1x/support#support-dl-bios

---

**Update #1:**

The `fsck` solved some inode problems.

`memtest` passed with 0 errors.

Comment: Thank you @heynnema, that's very kind to post so much. I'll do all that over the rainy weekend ahead! I am somewhat scared to update the BIOS though... I really don't want to brick my PC...

Comment: @Roger06 status please..,

Comment: Sorry @heynnema, been one of those weeks! I've done your first suggestion - I got one error on the main HD (though stupidly forgot to note down exactly what it was - something about something being able to be shorter) which I chose to fix. All other disks reported no errors. I will run the mem test next but need to pluck up courage to do the bios. Thanks

Comment: BTW - system had been fine all week but an hour ago I just clicked a link in Firefox and the whole lot froze again.

Comment: @Roger06 Keep in mind that this may be a difficult problem to solve. My answer covers the obvious basics that have to be taken to eliminate those as causes. We may still have an issue with video drivers... btw... what video card are you using? Nvidia? If so, what model and what version driver? We could also have another software problem, like rambox causing issues. Keep me posted (more frequently...).

Comment: graphics card is - [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn XT [Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition]. I'm not sure how (in Ubuntu) I check if I have the correct / latest drivers.

Comment: It looks like 19.20 may be the most current... their web site is a little unclear, and may require some extra digging on your part. See [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-7000-series/amd-radeon-hd-7870-ghz-edition). To see what version you have, try `dpkg -l *amd*`.

Comment: Thanks @heynnema. Output from that command gives - ii  xserver-xorg-vide 19.0.1-1ubunt amd64         X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver   - so guess I'm behind.

Comment: Up arrow clicked - what's it for?

Comment: Thanks. I have used hundreds of forums over the years but have never come across a feature like that. I am going to update the graphic driver (well, try). Do you know if a TimeShift back up would be able to restore if things go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Well I ran the driver update. Loads of output but the last line read "WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel". The output of dpkg -l *amd* has stayed the same as before so I guess it's failed? No clue what to do next.

Comment: @Roger06 Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `uname -r`. Did you use the amdgpu-install script?

Comment: Yes used that script. System is now screwed and won't boot. I get 'Failed to start user manger for UID121'. Nightmare. Can boot in recovery mode. Can I restore Time Shift from here? Don't want to make it worse.

Comment: @Roger06 I see that you successfully ran their amdgpu-uninstall... but now you have no video drivers, and screen updates/etc will be very slow. I suspect that their dkms driver wouldn't build on kernel 5.3.0-40-generic. Contact AMD for help, with that information.

Comment: Thanks for all you generous help, but this is all too much hassle, I think I'll just have to live with the odd crash.  Is the kernel too old or too recent? Would an Nvidia card be the answer? (It seems Da Vinci Resolve doesn't work with AMD so I may need to upgrade it anyway - but I was led to believe Nvidia cards were more of a problem). I think another answer is to buy a very cheap PC for me to experiment with as it's too stressful breaking  the PC I rely for work and home tasks.  Thanks.

Comment: @Roger06 I understand your position. However, as you mention earlier, there appear to be numerous problems with your system. The best scenario would be to handle each problem as it arose, and not to wait until you have so many problems as to make your system unstable, and difficult to repair. I've pointed out just some of the items that need attention. A new computer would require the same attention. However, Ubuntu 20.04 is due in April, so maybe you can try that... **don't upgrade, do a clean install**.

Comment: Problem seems to happen about every third time I wake the system from sleep. Have looked in kern.log but nothing obvious (but I don't know what I'm looking for). On Googling it it seems quite a common problem.

Comment: @Roger06 Unless you're willing/able to follow the instructions in my answer, there's nothing else I can suggest at this time.

Comment: fair enough. Just thought it might throw some light on it. I'm trying to do a memory test (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MemoryTest) but can't find this GRUB menu. I'll admit I'm just to scared to upgrade the BIOS after attempts to upgrade the graphics drivers ended in near disaster....

Comment: @Roger06 those memory test instructions are kind of old. Use the process shown in my answer :-)

Comment: I'm trying! I boot from the memtest USB and just get a blinking cursor and not the menu. Gave up after half an hour as watched a YouTube video that showed its menu pop up almost straight away. Going to try again now.

Comment: Test running. Was booting wrong device! Internal HD and USB both just show as Toshiba. (sorry)

Comment: Memtest showed 0 errors. Good news I suppose, but the search goes on. I'll have another go at upgrading graphics card and will investigate firmware upgrade for motherboard.